# Columns are aggregated incompletely

Tags: sql, hana

This is my table

```
ID|CREATED|VER     |
--+-------+--------+
61|  NULL |2023.4.6|
61|  NULL |  null  |
```

Did aggregation on all of the columns like this

```
SELECT ID,
 SUM(CASE WHEN CREATED IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CREATED_AGG,
 SUM(CASE WHEN VER IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VER_AGG
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID, CREATED, VER
```

result

```
ID|CREATED_AGG|VER_AGG           |
--+-----------+------------------+
61|          0|                 0|
61|          0|                 1|
```

I think below is the expected result. Why does it look like it is not fully aggregated?

```
ID|CREATED_AGG|VER_AGG           |
--+-----------+------------------+
61|          0|                 1|
```

Comment: Why did you include `CREATED` and `VER` in the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: `GROUP BY id, created, ver`  means "I want one result row per id/created/ver combination in the table". You don't want that. You want one result row per ID.

Comment: I kind of now get why it is shown as such after posting. But the reason I tried to aggregate these columns were because I needed to check
1. if there is any non-NULL value in CREATED
2. if there is any NULL value in VER

Comment: You're checking that inside the aggregation, so it's fine, you don't need to `GROUP BY` those columns anymore. You only need the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result for the data and query provided is correct and reproducible on all standard compliant SQL databases.

The `NULL`s in columns `CREATED` and `VER` are grouped into *separate* groups - thus resulting in multiple result rows - since `NULL` is not considered comparable to "other" `NULL`s. So, the `NULL`s are not in the same group.

To achieve the desired outcome, grouping just by `ID` does the trick.